# XPath - Converting UTC to time string [XPATH 1.0]

Tags: xml, xpath

I've got the following xpath expression converting a UTCTime to this format: `1 D, 2h,  10 min, 10 sec`:

```
concat(floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 8640),' D ',floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 360) mod 24,' h ', floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 60) mod 60,' min ',Duration/DurationUTC mod 60,' sec')
```

if The result is 2 hour, I will have `0 D, 0h,  10 min, 0 sec` as a result.

Question is: How can I hide `0D and 0h` and just show `10 min, 0 sec` in this situation?

is an IF statement the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using XPath 1.0 alone.

You could use predicates to test *node* values, for example:

```
Duration/DurationUTC[boolean(floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 8640))]
```

This would return, when the `floor` evaluates to zero, an empty node-set which would be converted to an empty string in a `concat`. But you have no way to do something like that with the `D` string. The result would be worse `D, h, 10min, 0 sec`.

If you have control of your source document, and can store the strings `D`, `h` in your source as text nodes you would be able to use predicates to select them. For example, if your source has something like:

```
<labels>
    <day-label>D,</day-label>
    <hour-label>h,</hour-label>
</labels>
```

you could use

```
concat(Duration/DurationUTC [boolean(floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 8640))], //labels/day-label[boolean(floor(Duration/DurationUTC div 8640))])
```

to print either nothing (if the `floor` result is zero) or `10D,` if it's `10`.

If you have support for XPath 2.0 you can use:

```
concat(
    if (/Duration/DurationUTC div 8640 > 1)  
         then concat(floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 8640),' D ') 
         else '',
    if ((/Duration/DurationUTC div 360) mod 24 > 1)  
         then concat(floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 360) mod 24,' h ') 
         else '',
    floor(/Duration/DurationUTC div 60) mod 60,' min ',
    /Duration/DurationUTC mod 60,' sec'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have control of the source document.

Comment: You can still solve the problem if you can add XPath 2.0 support to your processor, and use `if` expressions.

Comment: OK how would the expression look like?

Comment: I added it to the answer.